# How to add thumbnails to Discord embeds?

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a Discord bot that displays player statistics from Hypixel, a Minecraft server. I am trying to add their player's avatars as well, as a thumbnail in the embeds the bot sends. To get the avatars I am using [Crafatar](https://crafatar.com). This is the code I am using, however, the thumbnail doesn't show up on the embed. I believe this has something to do with the fact that I am using an URL with a variable in it, as I tried with just a regular URL and it worked fine.

```js
.setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.jpg`)
```

The variable `uuid` is declared and assigned to a value further up in my code.

**EDIT 1**

This is the code where I get the `uuid` variable from. I can't see anything wrong with it, however, I am not particularly skilled in JavaScript.

```js
var uuid = '';
getId(args[1]).then(id => {
  uuid = id;
})
```

`getId` is a function defined below, which looks like this:

```js
function getId(playername) {
  return fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${playername}`)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(player => player.id);
}
```

This uses the Mojang API to convert the player's display name, which is entered as a command parameter, to their UUID.

Comment: It seems fine from here. Are you sure `uuid` is defined correctly? If you do `console.log(uuid)` what gets printed?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more details. I tried adding the `console.log` and it printed nothing, which means that you're right, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, it seems like the problem is from the fact that you're correctly using Promises to set the value of `uuid`, but you're not waiting for it to be set before setting your embed thumbnail.
You should wait for it either using `Promise.then()` (as you did elsewhere), or `async/await`.
Here's an example:

```js
// Using .then():
getId(args[1]).then(uuid => {
  let embed = new MessageEmbed()

  // You have to set the thumbnail after you get the actual ID:
  embed.setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.jpg`)

  // You can now send the embed
})

// Using async/await:
let uuid = await getId(args[1])
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
embed.setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.jpg`)
```